# Is there a way to load multiple iframes with a single request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have multiple iframes in my website and all of them loads the same URL typed by the user. Each iframe makes a single request to get the webpage. I want to know if it is a way to make one single request and load all the iframes with the content. I tried using this code:

```
 function loadFrames(){
  $.get( "http://example.com", function( data ) { 
        allFrames.each(function(index) {
            var frame = allFrames[index];
            frame.contentWindow.document.write(data);
        }
 });
```

But the problem is that it doesnt load the css and javascript of webpages well.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while ago. I saved the returned data as a Blob of HTML type, and then assigned that as the source of the iframe. There are plenty of online examples, but the jist is:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/html'});
var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
iframe_1.src = blob_url;
```

At this point you could forEach of your iframe array and assign the src to each. Check out method 2 for more of an idea of what I am getting at:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/

Comment: Thanks, but I just tested it and it doesn't load the CSS and js neither.